# Is every orientable surface a 2-folded covering of a non-orientable surface?

Tags: algebraic-topology, surfaces, covering-spaces

We learned that every non-orientable surface can be covered by an orientable surface 2-foldedly. But what about the statement that "Is every orientable surface a 2-folded covering of a non-orientable surface?"

Comment: I don't have time for a full answer, but yes.  Idea:  think of $\mathbb{R}P^2$ by cutting $S^2$ in half, throwing a way a piece, and gluing antipodal points on the boundary.  This works for any surface with an even number of holds.  Next, think of the Klein bottle $K$ by cutting $T^2$ in half, throwing away a piece, and gluing the two boundary circles together while reversing orientation.  This works for any surface with an odd number of holes.

Comment: @JasonDeVito. Nice way of thinking -- but why can we claim that it works with odd number of holes?

Comment: For a $3$-holed torus, for example, cutting it in half leaves two "hole an a half" tori - a torus with a cylinder connected to it.  It has boundary consisting of 2 circles - glue them just like you do on a cylinder to get a Klein bottle.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that $k\mathbb{RP}^2$ is a non-orientable surface with Euler characteristic $2 - k$. Its orientable double cover is a closed orientable surface with Euler characteristic $2(2 - k) = 4 - 2k = 2 - 2(k - 1)$; by the classification of closed surfaces, it must be $\Sigma_{k-1}$. So every closed orientable surface occurs as the orientable double cover of some non-orientable surface.